# Is it possible to play the practice mode with random characters?

Tags: awesomenauts

Is there anyway way to play a practice game with other characters than Clunk, Sheriff and Leon ?  Could be useful to train against particular characters and skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I wish it, no, there is not a way. They are the default computer characters, and I've never seen an NPC be a character besides those three.